# Why array_search doesn't work in this case?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Why my in this code array_search doesn't work? I use it without $_POST and all work well. But now I can't understand.

```
<_php

    $arr = array(
        'Tokyo' => 'Japan',
        'Mexico City' => 'Mexico',
        'New York City' => 'USA',
        'Mumbai' => 'India',
        'Seoul' => 'Korea',
        'Shanghai' => 'China',
        'Lagos' => 'Nigeria',
        'Buenos Aires' => 'Argentina',
        'Cairo' => 'Egypt',
        'London' => 'England');

    ?>


    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="exercise.php">
            <select name="city">
                <?php
                    foreach ($arr as $a => $b)
                    {
                        echo "<option>$a</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>

            <input type="submit" value="get a city">

        </form>

        <?php
        if ($_POST)
        {
            $city=$_POST['city'];

            $country=array_search($city, $arr);

            echo "<p>$city is in $country.</p>" ;

        }
        ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I've checked type of $country and it's string, also I've tried use $_POST['city'] instead $country but it still doesn't work. 
What have I done wrong?

Comment: Because the city is the key not the value.  Try: `$country = $arr[$city];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `array_search()`, just use the index value directly:

```
$city = $_POST['city'];
$country = $arr[$city];
echo "<p>$city is in $country.</p>" ;
```

Answer (score 1):

array_search() does not work here, as array_search is searching the values of the array, not the keys.

As you have the key, the best option is, as Alex suggests. However you should also check the key exists first, using array_key_exists(), as you cannot guarantee the value in your $_POST will be one of the ones you are expecting which would cause an E_NOTICE to be thrown if not.

```
$country = (array_key_exists($city, $arr)) ? $arr[$city] : null;
```

[array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php),
[array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)